# Exception : buildSessionFactory - in Hibernate App

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, configuration

I'm working on an E-Commerce App using Hibernate Framework. But I'm facing a problem during the execution. The test program throws an Exception :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:19)
    at HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:9)
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1708)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1617)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:14)
    ... 2 more
```

**My HibernateUtil :**

```
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory>
            <!-- local connection properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecom</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>

            <!-- dialect for MySQL -->
                <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
            <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
            <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>



            <mapping class="Metier.Category"/>
            <mapping class="Metier.Customer"/>
            <mapping class="Metier.CustomerOrder"/>
            <mapping class="Metier.orderedProduct"/>
            <mapping class="Metier.orderedProductID"/>
            <mapping class="Metier.Product"/>

      </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Please tell me what is the source of the Exception. 
Cheers.

Comment: I've had a similar bug where an exception gets thrown, and subsequently mishandled, swallowing the original exception. If you have access to the Hibernate source code (I don't know which version you are using), try debugging. Set a breakpoint on InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1708 and see what exception is being mishandled by Hibernate.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your comment ! Actually i'm using Hibernate 5 , I've tried to access to "InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1708", but the access is denied. Any other solution, please ? Regards

Comment: Consider downloading the source code and inspecting that line directly, and see what could be null. So if you see object.method(), check what the object is. That should give a clue.

Comment: Did you ever come across the cause of the exception? I am having the same problem!